# Перемещение файлов внутри docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner, containers

У меня зарегистрирован docker gitlab-runner, в нем на след стейдже копируются файлы из папки с репой в папку расшаренную между контейнером и сервером-хостом, но раннер почему-то ее не видит, как это преодолеть?

Стейдж из раннера

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
#    - ls -lha /www/$deploy_subfolder
    - cp -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR_done /www/$deploy_subfolder/${ENV}_$CI_COMMIT_SHA
#    - ls -lha /www/$deploy_subfolder/${ENV}_$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - cp -r /www/$deploy_subfolder/${ENV}_$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA /www/$deploy_subfolder/prev-version || true
#    - cp -rP $CI_PROJECT_DIR $docker_html_path/$deploy_subfolder/${ENV}_$CI_COMMIT_SHA  # copy CI_PROJECT_DIR into /var/www/"hype-dev or hype-prod"/${ENV}_$CI_COMMIT_SHA
#    - cp -vP $docker_html_path/html $docker_html_path/prev-verions/$deploy_subfolder/$CI_COMMIT_SHA || true #copy simlink  from /var/www/html/ to /var/www/"hype-dev or hype-prod"/${ENV}_$CI_COMMIT_SHA/prev-version
  artifacts:
    when: always
    name: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - tests/js/screenshots/

deploy-dev:
      extends: deploy
      stage: deploy
      variables:
        ENV: dev
        deploy_subfolder: "hype-dev"
      when: always
      only:
    #    - develop
        - ned_runner
      tags:
        - test_new_runner
```

Папка в контейнере существует:
[image: Папка в контейнере]

Ошибка в раннере:

```
Using docker image sha256:c4825e3ad0feedc9c2c39d218e408249514f4409d2e7c91702587931a0450477 for ruby:2.7 with digest ruby@sha256:5a81b132459c16a2b5d6b2741099de7c6209c545cbfd8539e3c501eb13cd5ca5 ...
$ echo "--------- STARTING WORK ------------"
--------- STARTING WORK ------------
$ ls -lha /www/$deploy_subfolder
ls: cannot access '/www/hype-dev': No such file or directory
Uploading artifacts for failed job
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в логике раннера, ошибочно не то написал в символ ссылке